# Blender 2.79 to 2.8 Animation Error

Tags: rendering, animation

I have a problem when I transfer my jelly fish Project from Blender 2.79 to 2.8. Everything works fine in 2.79 but in the render of 2.8 the bell of my jelly is rendered at the origin of it's parent object (an empty), even though everything looks fine in the viewport.
Any advice or is this a bug maybe?

Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf4ju.jpg

File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tLCzx5cvcyOmlGbYImVYJ6Thq3f7OrML

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with unfinished experimental development versions of Blender

Comment: No, please don't. The contributor is only unable to express the problem. Check the images and the blend file.